# Symfony2: Issue with foreign key when saving OneToOne related entity

Tags: symfony, entity

I have a simple usecase:

- i create a contactdetails entity
- i create a user entity
- i add the new contactdetails object to the user entity with `$user->setContactdetails($contactdetails);`
- then i persist both

  ```
  $contactdetails = new Contactdetails();
  $user = new User();
  $user->setContactdetails($contactdetails);

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($contactdetails);
  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();
  ```

i have done that 1000 times like this. but now something strange happens:

```
   An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (contactdetails_id) VALUES (?)' with params [2175]:

   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inscouts`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `FK_8D93D64998778544` FOREIGN KEY (`contactdetails_id`) REFERENCES `Contactdetails` (`id`))
```

I cannot explain what is the problem, because the contactdetails entity is created correctly. it just cannot be saved to the user :/

**Edit:**

Mapping info (User entity):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="...\FrontendBundle\Entity\Contactdetails")
 */
private $contactdetails;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="...\FrontendBundle\Entity\Medialinks")
 */
private $medialinks;
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping info?

Comment: did. was that what u needed?

Comment: the thing is, the user entity is in bundle A, contactdetails is in bundle B. 

i have tried now the same with another entity in bundle B and it worked. could that be the problem, cross bundle relation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the **Contactdetails** first.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$contactdetails = new Contactdetails();
$em->persist($contactdetails);

$user = new User();
$user->setContactdetails($contactdetails);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```